# xcodebuild: error: DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR in Xcode 15

Tags: xcode

I am trying to publish SDK into Cocoa pods.

(pod spec lint --verbose TravelSafelyBoneshell.podspec)

When i run the above command then its showing me below error:

```
Testing with `xcodebuild`. 
 -> Travel (1.0.29)
    - WARN  | license: Invalid license type.
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (3 targets)
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  error: DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead (in target 'Travel' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
post_install do |installer|
  xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # For xcode 15+ only
      if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
pod install
```

in terminal

Comment: Thanks,
I have already tried with above code and its not working.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 15, Apple made a modification to the variable that points to the default toolchain location, replacing $DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with $TOOLCHAIN_DIR. If your project or target relies on the previous variable, you should update it to use $TOOLCHAIN_DIR.

To perform this replacement, you can add the following code snippet at the end of your project's Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

After making this change in your Podfile, you will need to install the pods again via the terminal using the command:

```
pod install
```